# /usr/bin/cut: Argument list too long in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I loaded a csv file into a variable and then I am trying to cut out some columns which results in this error **/usr/bin/cut: Argument list too long**. Here is what I did:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then 
    echo "you need to add the file name as argument"
fi 

echo "input file name $1"
input_file=$(<$1)

#cut the required columns. 
cut_input_file=$(cut -f 1,2,3,5,8,9,10 -d \| $input_file)

echo $(head $cut_input_file)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Read about [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs). You should not backslash the `|` pipe

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Where have they used `xargs` ?

Comment: `xargs` is often the solution for *Argument list too long*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks, I will recheck it despite that i've been there and didn't get the way it works. \| is separator for the csv file.

Comment: Just to be clear about all these `xargs` comments: The problem with your snippet is described by below in the answers and `xargs` isn't the correct way to fix it. Your input file has too many words and using them all as arguments to `cut` hits the limits of the console. `xargs` is usually used to get around this limit, it gets a list from standard input (which isn't limited), and execute the command *multiple times* avoiding to hit the argument limits (the amount, order, etc can be controlled), but in your case you should be supplying your data through standard input, and not through arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason of that error is your use of `$input_file` which has full file data.

You need to run `cut` on the file not on the file content so use:

```
cut -f 1,2,3,5,8,9,10 -d '|' "$1"
```

To run `cut` against file content use:

```
cut -f 1,2,3,5,8,9,10 -d '|' <<< "$input_file"
```